# length header suddenly has wrong value when use read int32?

Tags: c#, networking, io

I wrote a tcp listener to receive a sequence of images from single client , this is the code of server :

```
new Thread(() =>
{
  while (true)
  {
    displayingFrame.Start(); // another thread to display images
    Socket socket = listener.AcceptSocket();
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
    client.Client = socket;
    Debug.WriteLine("Connection accepted.");

    var childSocketThread = new Thread(() =>
    {
      NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
      BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ns);

      while (true)
      {
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            int length = br.ReadInt32();

            Debug.WriteLine("length : " + length);

            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int totalReaded = 0;
            int readed = 0;
            while (totalReaded < length)
            {
                readed = br.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
                ms.Write(buf, 0, readed);
                totalReaded += readed;
            }

            byte[] frame = ms.ToArray();
            this.frames.Enqueue(frame);
            Debug.WriteLine("frame enqueued with length " + frame.Length);

        }
      }
    });
    childSocketThread.Start();
  }
}).Start();
```

it receive frames very well but suddenly `br.ReadInt32();` returns a very big length so `br.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);` takes a very long time writing to memory stream and it writes a wrong data inside frame .

this is the client :

```
TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, 20000));
NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(ns);
while ( true )
{
    byte[] frame = Screenshot();

    bw.Write(frame.Length);
    Console.WriteLine("a frame length has flushed : " + frame.Length);

    bw.Write(frame);
    Console.WriteLine("a frame itself has flushed");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

and here the debug info :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the hex value you're getting - `1196314761` - you'll get `0x474E5089` and finally convert to ASCII you will get `GNP\x89` which gives us the known magic value `\x89PNG` that is the marker of PNG file. You're actually reading the content of your screenshot as the length.

Make sure that you're code for reading the data does not read too much from the previous frame. I think you code for reading the data does not include the fact that you might get content of 2 frames in one `.Read` but then later you just don't care if you have too much data. You only check if it's not less than length.

Comment: thank you very much ,,, it seems that is was reading the frame data instead of the length , it's because i didn't check if the buffer fit the data , the code works very well now